# Reading Chart Label Values Runtime-Error (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below table for which I am creating a chart:

[image: Table]

After adding the chart I want to color the chart bars based on the label values and if the value of the label is 0 then the label should be changed to "OFF".

Below is my code to do so:

```
Dim ChartRng As Range

Set ChartRng = Worksheets("Overview").Range("A1:C19")

Dim oChtObj As ChartObject
Set oChtObj = Worksheets("Overview").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=48, Width:=570, Top:=1000, Height:=367)

With oChtObj.Chart
    .Parent.Name = "Performance"
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .ApplyLayout (1)
    .SetSourceData ChartRng
    .HasLegend = True
    .SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
    .SeriesCollection(2).HasDataLabels = False
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Caption = "Call Facing Time (KPI: 75%) Per Agent"
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 16
    .ChartTitle.Font.Color = RGB(84, 84, 84)
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "CFT"
    .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "KPI"
    .SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
    .ChartStyle = 26
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = False
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .Legend.LegendEntries(1).Delete
    .SeriesCollection(2).Border.Color = RGB(37, 64, 97)
    .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.Weight = 3
    .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Size = 9
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 9
    .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Color = RGB(77, 77, 77)
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Color = RGB(77, 77, 77)
    .Legend.Position = xlBottom
    .Legend.Font.Size = 9
    .SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Font.Size = 9
    .ChartArea.Border.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Border.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
End With

Set oChtObj = Nothing

Dim oPoint As Excel.Point
Dim sngPercente As Single

For Each oPoint In Worksheets("Overview").ChartObjects("Performance").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points
sngPercente = CSng(Split(oPoint.DataLabel.Caption, "%")(0))

With oPoint
If sngPercente < 70 Then
.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
If sngPercente > 75 Then
.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
End If
If sngPercente >= 70 And sngPercente <= 75 Then
.Interior.Color = RGB(148, 208, 80)
End If
If sngPercente = 0 Then
.DataLabel.Caption = "OFF"
End If
End With

Next oPoint
```

For some reason I get the below error at the line `sngPercente = CSng(Split(oPoint.DataLabel.Caption, "%")(0))`:

[image: Error]

I have also tried using `Split(oPoint.DataLabel.Text` but was still getting an error.

It is noteworthy that the same code was running fine when viewed in Excel 2013, however it gives the above error in 2007.

Any help understanding the reason behind the error or possible workarounds will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if Excel 2007 has [Datalabel.Caption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839622%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property as I cannot test it.

Try this

Add this line

`Worksheets("Overview").ChartObjects("Performance").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True`

before the `For Each oPoint In Worksheets("Overview").....` Loop and now try it.

If it still doesn't work then I will delete this post.

**EDIT**

As per [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb179578%28v=office.12%29.aspx) this property exists in Office 2007

Further testing on Teamviewer showed that in this version you have to select the Datalabel first before reading it's value. So all we had to do was add

```
oPoint.DataLabel.Select
```

before

```
sngPercente = CSng(Split(oPoint.DataLabel.Caption, "%")(0))
```

and everything went smoothly.

Comment: Still the same error even after adding the line as you suggested. http://i60.tinypic.com/ogi9v4.png http://i58.tinypic.com/124vr82.png Maybe there is some library I need to load or something else I am missing?

Comment: I don't have Excel 2007. But if you have teamviewer then I can check it for you

Comment: Mmm... not sure about teamview as I am running this on the company computer and I will probably not be allowed to install it. But here is a copy of the excel file if that helps: https://db.tt/myJERxI5

Comment: Let me see If I can test it at a friends pc who has excel 2007

Comment: Thanks a lot. So is there another way that I can try to do this. Maybe a different syntax or function?

Comment: Did you try using `ApplyDataLabels` instead of just setting `HasDataLabels` to `True`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have come home and installed Office 2007 on a virtual machine that I have created, and the code ran without any errors!!! At work I get an error (I tried on more than one computer). This is very very strange :(

Comment: @SiddharthRout So I have done some research by cloning the virtual machines and installing a different service pack on Office 2007 each time. The code works fine with no SP, works fine with SP2, but fails with SP3. So was something specific changed in Service Pack 3 that causes the error? If so, any possible workaround?

Comment: That is an interesting observation :) I really want to help you but with out access to a machine where it is not working, I really don't know what to suggest. I am sorry.

Comment: Well now that I could emulate the error at home by installing Office 2007 SP3, I can totally install TeamViewer so you can have a look!

Comment: @SiddharthRout My TeamViewer ID is: 688 676 137, please let me know once you are connecting so I can post the password.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Just a small followup, is it possible to **Deselect** the label and the chart after executing the code. Right now after running it, the last label with the chart remain selected

Comment: Select a range in the worksheet and that will deselect the label :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks, that will work provided the chart is inserted in to the same sheet from which the code is run. But when inserting the chart in "Sheet2" for example and then viewing that sheet, you will see the chart and the last label still selected. I have tried `ActiveChart.Deselect` at the end of my code, but that didn't do anything :(

Comment: @SiddharthRout Just out of curiosity you might wanna check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326925/deselect-label-and-chart-excel-vba/25327636#25327636 I think it's the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your data label shows the Y value, right? Skip the data label and go straight to the values.

```
Dim vYVals As Variant
Dim srs As Series
Dim iPt as Long
Dim dPctg As Double ' NO ADVANTAGE TO SINGLE OVER DOUBLE

Set srs = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
vYVals = srs.Values

For iPt = 1 to srs.Points.Count
  dPctg = vYVals(iPt)

  With srs.Points(iPt)
    Select Case dPctg
      Case 0
        .DataLabel.Caption = "OFF"
      Case < 0.7
        .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Case > 0.75
        .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
      Case Else
        .Interior.Color = RGB(148, 208, 80)
    End Select
  End With
Next
```